# Help in viewing the output of a neural network

Tags: matlab

I used *nftool* in Matlab 2012 and trained a network. I gave the training inputs as x=[250:1] and targets as t=[250:1]. I used 10 hidden layers. I trained the network and got the results and exported the data to workspace. I finally got net as the variable in the workspace. I want to realize this network in hardware. So, I want the exact weights and bias values. I searched the net and typed net.IW and got 10 values, net.LW and got yet another 10 values and net.b and got 11 values. My network diagram is as shown below:

[image: Output Neural Net]

If IW is the Input Weight and LW is the Layer Weight, I realized the network diagram as shown below:

[image: My realization of output Neural Network]

I got 10 values for IW, which would fit into 10 hidden layers, and 10 values for LW, which will fit into 10 hidden layers according to my realization. I got 11 values for bias, which will fit in to my network, since there are 11 (b) blocks in the network. 
But, i am missing one IW and one LW value.

I want to know whether there is a mistake in my realization of the output of the network or I missed any of the values. Please help.

Comment: Looks like you have one hidden layer with ten neurons and not ten hidden layers.

Comment: @Aaron No, in the second picture, Hidden is not my editing. So, its 10 hidden layers only. I also specified 10 hidden layers during training.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understand correctly your IW should be [1*10] as it takes 1-dim input to 10-dim hidden layer
than 
LW should be [10*1] as it takes 10-dim hidden to 1-dim output,
b should be 10 for the hidden layer and 1 for the output layer

Why do you think your'e missing something?